# Window Service (C#) and oracle connection lost contact error (ora-03135)

Tags: c#, oracle, windows-services, oracle10g

I have a server built through window services and DB is Oracle 10g.
In multi user environment, server often frequently logs Oracle connection lost contact exception (ora-03135).

Upon googling, I found some instructions but that did not solve my problem.

1. Add a program to window firewall.
2. Modify expire time and inbound connections in sql.net ora file.

Comment: Show us how you init your connections and connection strings

Comment: ADO.NET is used with generic DB Access Pattern and connection strings are defined in config file. Do the oracle MTU, SDU, TDU has an impact because the server is hits are greater . 250 persons across the cities are accessing the server for processing of their requests?